# Stop ajax refresh after 5 minutes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following code that refreshes a PHP file every 9 seconds. This works ok but I would like to have a timeout in case a user leaves the page open. It should stop refreshing the call after 5 minutes otherwise it will keep loading my PHP file undefinitely wasting server resources. What is the most simple and efficient way to do this with jQuery?

Here is my code:

```
(function($)
{
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $.ajaxSetup(
            {
                cache: false,
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $('#content').show();
                },
                complete: function() {
                    $('#content').show();
                },
                success: function() {
                    $('#content').show();
                }
            });
        const $container = $("#content");
        $container.load("example.php");
        const refreshId = setInterval(function () {
            $container.load('example.php');

        }, 9000);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I would suggest getting `new Date()` when it starts and then check if 5 min have passed each time you perform the AJAX call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't replicate your example. Consider the following somewhat similar example.

```js
$(function() {
  function updateBeat() {
    var b = parseInt($(".beats").text()) + 1;
    $(".beats").html(b);
  }

  function checkNow() {
    console.log(start, Date.now(), Date.now() - start);
    return !(Date.now() - start < (5 * 60 * 1000));
  }

  function showNow() {
    $(".seconds").html(Math.round((Date.now() - start) / 1000));
  }

  function reload(frame, url) {
    $(frame).load(url);
  }

  var start = Date.now();
  var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
    if (checkNow()) {
      console.log("Sleep");
      clearInterval(refreshId);
      return false;
    }
    //reload($("#content"), 'example.php');
    updateBeat();
    showNow();
  }, 9000);
})
```

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="show-beats"><label>Beats:</label><span class="beats">0</span></div>
<div class="show-time"><label>Seconds:</label><span class="seconds">0</span></div>
```

You can use `Date.now()` or you can use `new Date()`. Either way you want to capture the Date Time when the script begins and then `clearInterval()` when enough time has passes.

Comment: Or, as the duplicate shows, just call `clearInterval` inside a `setTimeout`:).

Comment: @HereticMonkey more than one way... both work.